# How to get render parameter

Tags: dialog, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I want to get render parameter.

I wrote the following aui:script for opening new dialog. In that script I set parameter.

```
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>weburl" size="75: id="weburl" label="" inlineField="true"  />  
<aui:button name="btnPreview" id="btnPreview" value="Preview"/>

<aui:script>
    AUI().use('aui-base','aui-io-plugin-deprecated','liferay-util-window','liferay-portlet-url', 'aui-dialog-iframe-deprecated', function(A) {
        A.one('#<portlet:namespace />btnPreview').on('click', function(event){

            alert(document.getElementById('weburl').value)
            var strUrl=document.getElementById('weburl').value;
            var renderURL =Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
            renderURL.setParameter("nameUrl",strUrl);
            renderURL.setParameter("mvcPath",'/html/view2.jsp');
            renderURL.setPortletId("Portlets_WAR");
            renderURL .setWindowState("pop_up");

            alert(renderURL.toString());

            var popUpWindow=Liferay.Util.Window

                .getWindow({
                    dialog: {
                        centered: true,
                        constrain2view: true,

                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        width: 500
                    }
                })

                .plug(A.Plugin.DialogIframe, {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    iframeCssClass: 'dialog-iframe',
                    uri:'<%=portletSettingsURL.toString()%>'
                })

                .render();

            popUpWindow.show();
            popUpWindow.titleNode.html("Image Preview");
            popUpWindow.io.start();
        });
    });
</aui:script>
```

Using this script i redirect to my view2.jsp and open that page in dialog succesfully. Here I also set the parameter using :

> var strUrl=document.getElementById('weburl').value
>                     var testurl =Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
>                     testurl.setParameter("name",strUrl);

My portal:renderURL is as follow

```
 <portlet:renderURL var="portletSettingsURL"
 windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString()%>">
       <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/view2.jsp"/>
         </portlet:renderURL>
```

My view2.jsp file is as follow

```
 <%

String str1=renderRequest.getParameter("nameUrl");

System.out.print("value " +str1);

%>
```

**I want to send my weburl textbox value to view2.jsp file**

I just want the value of name in my view2.jsp file
How can I get my value in view2.jsp file?

Comment: Well, you have  to set parameter in url which you  are opening in dialog. You havent  used  portleturl  which has parameter in dialog .

Comment: I used portlet render url <portlet:renderURL var="portletSettingsURL" windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString()%>">
      <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/view2.jsp"/>

 </portlet:renderURL>

Comment: You haven't set parameter in portletSettingsURL. It should be set with portletSettingsURL only.

Comment: I get my value in script tag using var strUrl=document.getElementById('weburl').value. I want to set this value in param. for ex.<portlet:param name="weburl" value=??/> How can i set value attribute?

Comment: well, you already have created testurl using javascript, use that testurl in DialogIframe itself.

Comment: can you please give me example.How can i do this?

Comment: `var strUrl=document.getElementById('weburl').value
                var testurl =Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
                testurl.setParameter("name",strUrl);testurl.setParameter("mvcPath",'/html/view2.jsp');testurl.setWindowState("pop_up");`  use this testurl as uri in dialogiframe

Comment: sorry :( still it gives me null vale

Comment: Can you please update your question with what you have tried?

Comment: Please change uri in dialog-iframe with url that you created.(renderURL )

Comment: what  I have to put '<%=portletSettingsURL.toString()%>' instead of?? If i put uri:'renderURL' then not working properly

Comment: Use `uri: "'" + renderURL +"'"`

Comment: Just add portlet namespace in render url and see if it works or not

Comment: Thanks for reply but no change.. it doesn't redirect to my view2.jsp file

Comment: Thanks @LuckyBoy can u give me example?

Comment: uri:'#<portlet:namespace />renderURL' not working

Comment: Hi @PankajKathiriya if i  tried your solution uri: "'" + renderURL +"'" then it will open my current page not view2.jsp..What else I need to add???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tired the ParamUtil class?

ParamUtil.get(request, param, defaultValue).

For putting params to the URL you can check this. This is for scriptlet but you can use it in AUI script too.

https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/43775763

Edit:
You can add your parameter to the URL like this:`url = url + '&<portlet:namespace/>yourParamName=yourParamValue'`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `renderRequest.getParameter("name")`, it shoud work.

Comment: No, still it gives me null value